# Window.close not Working in page Refernce Apex method

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, visualforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I have page reference method in apex controller.
I need to close the current tab .

Here is my code:

```
public PageReference savePostSurveyAnswer(){
        String sitePathPrefix = Site.getPathPrefix();
        System.debug('savePostSurveyAnswer method start');

        CaseIdentifierIdValue = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('caseIdentifierId');


        ShGl_PostChatSurvey__c postChatSurvey = new ShGl_PostChatSurvey__c(); 
        postChatSurvey.ShGl_SurveyQuestion1__c = question1;
        postChatSurvey.ShGl_SurveyQuestion2__c = question2;
        postChatSurvey.ShGl_SurveyQuestion3__c = question3;
        postChatSurvey.ShGl_SurveyQuestion4__c = question4;
        postChatSurvey.ShGl_SurveyResponse1__c = questionAnsSelected1; 
        postChatSurvey.ShGl_SurveyResponse2__c = questionAnsSelected2; 
        postChatSurvey.ShGl_SurveyResponse3__c = questionAnsSelected3; 
        postChatSurvey.ShGl_SurveyResponse4__c = questionAnsSelected4; 
        postChatSurvey.ShGl_Market_Code__c = 'US'; //new data base model
        postChatSurvey.ShGl_UniqueCaseIdentifier__c = CaseIdentifierIdValue;
        //postChatSurvey.ShGl_LiveTranscriptChatKey__c = chatKeyIdValue;
        //postChatSurvey.ShGl_CaseOfSurvey__c = (Id) LiveChatTranscriptObj.CaseId;   //through trigger     
        Database.SaveResult postSaveResult = Database.insert(postChatSurvey);
        return new PageReference('javascript:window.close();');
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you check the documentation for [Window.close()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) you will find the reason:

> This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened by a script using the window.open() method. If the window was not opened by a script, an error similar to this one appears in the console: Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.

In short: The browser won't let you. This is not specific to Salesforce or VF. `Windows.close()` would anyway not close a tab, but the whole browser window.

If you are looking to close a console tab, [this question/answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/150404/close-a-tab-in-a-console-with-a-vf-page-to-finish-a-flow) might provide what you are looking for.